VBA Set Variable Values using For Loop
I am trying to see if it's possible to set the values for large sets of variables using a For-Loop,  without attaching an integer to the end of the variable name. Been playing around with this for a bit but haven't found any solutions. I'm assuming it's not possible unless I structure the variable names like [Variable1, Variable2, Variable3 --- For Loop: Variable & I = ].
    **MODULE VARIABLES**
    Private ADwsLoadType As String
    Private ADwsShipDate As Date
    Private ADwsCustomer As String
    Private ADwsBOL As String
    Private ADwsLocation As String
    Private ADwsSOproduct As String
    Private ADwsSOsize As String
    Private ADwsSOweight As Long
    Private ADwsSOadjust As Long
    Private ADwsScaleWeight As Long
    Private ADwsLoadWeight As Long
    Private ADwsProduct1 As String
    Private ADwsProduct2 As String
    Private ADwsProduct3 As String
    Private ADwsProduct4 As String
    Private ADwsQty1 As Long
    Private ADwsQty2 As Long
    Private ADwsQty3 As Long
    Private ADwsQty4 As Long
    Private ADwsSize1 As String
    Private ADwsSize2 As String
    Private ADwsSize3 As String
    Private ADwsSize4 As String
    Private ADwsLoadEst1 As Long
    Private ADwsLoadEst2 As Long
    Private ADwsLoadEst3 As Long
    Private ADwsLoadEst4 As Long
    Private ADwsLoadAct1 As Double
    Private ADwsLoadAct2 As Double
    Private ADwsLoadAct3 As Double
    Private ADwsLoadAct4 As Double
    Private ADwsToteAct1 As Double
    Private ADwsToteAct2 As Double
    Private ADwsToteAct3 As Double
    Private ADwsToteAct4 As Double
    Private ADwsTLproduct As String
    Private ADwsTLweight As String
    Private ADwsTL90 As String
    
Private Sub SetVariables()
  Call OperationCwal    **Disable Calculation & Screen Updating**
  Call ShowMeTheMoney   **Set Values for Public Variables**
  With ADws
'**************************************************************************************************
    **Private Variables**
    Dim NamesArr As Variant
    NamesArr = Array(ADwsLoadType, ADwsShipDate, ADwsCustomer, ADwsBOL, ADwsLocation, _
                    ADwsSOproduct, ADwsSOsize, ADwsSOweight, ADwsSOadjust, _
                    ADwsScaleWeight, ADwsLoadWeight, ADwsProduct1, ADwsProduct2, _
                    ADwsProduct3, ADwsProduct4, ADwsQty1, ADwsQty2, ADwsQty3, ADwsQty4, _
                    ADwsSize1, ADwsSize2, ADwsSize3, ADwsSize4, ADwsLoadEst1, _
                    ADwsLoadEst2, ADwsLoadEst3, ADwsLoadEst4, ADwsLoadAct1, ADwsLoadAct2, _
                    ADwsLoadAct3, ADwsLoadAct4, ADwsToteAct1, ADwsToteAct2, _
                    ADwsToteAct3, ADwsToteAct4, ADwsTLproduct, ADwsTLweight, ADwsTL90)
    
    **Values**
    Dim ValueArr As Variant
    ValuesArr = Array(.[B7], .[B11], .[B15], .[B19], .[B23], .[F5], _
                      .[F6], .[J5], .[F6], .[F8], .[J8], .[E13], _
                      .[E15], .[E17], .[E19], .[F13], .[F15], .[F17], .[F19], _
                      .[G13], .[G15], .[G17], .[G19], .[I13], .[I15], .[I17], _
                      .[I19], .[J13], .[J15], .[J17], .[J19], .[K13], _
                      .[K15], .[K17], .[K19], .[E23], .[G23], .[J23])
                      
    For I = LBound(NamesArr) To UBound(NamesArr)
        If Values(I) = "" Then
            NamesArr(I) = ""
        Else
            NamesArr(I) = ValuesArr(I)
        End If
    Next I
    
    **IMMEDIATE WITH SHOULD RETURN "TANK"**

    Debug.Print ADwsLoadType    **Returned Value = ""**
    Debug.Print NamesArr(1)     **Returned Value = "Tank"**
    Debug.Print ValuesArr(1)    **Returned Value = "Tank"**

    **VALUE IS ASSOCIATED WITH BOTH ARRAYS BUT NOT WITH VARIABLE NAME**

'**************************************************************************************************
 End With
 Call BlackSheepWall    **Enable Calculation & Screen Updating**
End Sub```


It doesn't work as your expectd. But you can use Array. eg.  Private ADwsQty(1 To 4) As Long, assign value ADwsQty(1)=1, read its value Debug.Print ADwsQty(1).  Microsoft documentation:

Using arrays


Maybe an approach could be to use a dictionary like that
Option Explicit

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub testDict()
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    ' The following lines add key-value pairs to the dictionary.
    ' Each pair consists of a unique key (like "ADwsLoadType")
    ' and an associated value (like "Data ADwsLoadType").
    ' Note that #1/4/2024# is a date literal in VBA.
    
    dict.Add "ADwsLoadType", "Data ADwsLoadType"
    dict.Add "ADwsShipDate", #1/4/2024#
    dict.Add "ADwsCustomer", "Data ADwsCustomer"
    dict.Add "ADwsBOL", "Data ADwsBOL"
    dict.Add "ADwsLocation", "Data ADwsLocation"
    dict.Add "ADwsSOproduct", "Data ADwsSOproduct"
    ' and so on and so forth
    
    ' This block of code iterates through each key in the dictionary.
    ' For each key v, it prints the key and its associated value
    ' to the Immediate Window using Debug.Print.
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In dict
        Debug.Print v & " - " & dict(v)
    Next
    
    ' This section demonstrates how to change the value associated
    ' with a specific key in the dictionary.
    ' The line dict("ADwsLoadType") = "Data changed ADwsLoadType"
    ' updates the value for the key "ADwsLoadType".
        
    dict("ADwsLoadType") = "Data changed  ADwsLoadType"
    Debug.Print dict.Item("ADwsLoadType")
    
End Sub

Further reading on topics like dictionary and arrays
